# In 16th Century, How Hajis were verified, whether he is Muslim or not?

Tags: history, non-muslim, hajj, masjid-al-haram

In 15th and 16th Century,

How Government of Arabia or caretakers of Mecca verify that; a person who dressed like Haji; is Muslim or non-Muslim?

Comment: how is it done today?

Comment: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding in this question and the one before it. There is no strict process controlling entry to Makkah. Most cars are just waved through (especially if the people within them are wearing _ihram_).

Comment: @Ansari
I think you gave a brilliant answer to that question too. I was told to split question into general parts to get understanding of various subjects under that question. As per info i have; It was considered as capital crime in 16th Century and were very strict about it.

Comment: There are very few capital crimes in Islam, and entering Makkah as a non-Muslim is _not_ one of them.

Comment: Thanks. But Was it same in medieval period too? 16th Century?

Comment: Also your views on -> The Ottoman Empire ruled by the law of Hanafi and were responsible for the cities of Mecca and Medina and the empire lasted from 1229-1923. In an article of Mughal-Ottoman relations; during the reign of Akbar an interesting note on Hajj stated in an early document state that:

'No Muslims and believers in the unity of God', proclaims an Ottoman
imperial firman, 'should be hindered in any way if he wishes to visit
the Holy Cities and circumambulate the luminous Ka'ba.'42
42. M.D., vol. 6, f. 17, firman no. 39, 1564-5, quoted by Faroqhi, op. cit. 147.

Comment: Maybe a better place to ask this question would be History SE http://history.stackexchange.com/